# How does the janam kundli of 9 grahas, Surya graha, chandra graha, etc. look like?

Tags: astrology, navagraha

Do we have janam kundli of 9 grahas found in any scripture? What is the source?

Comment: question is unclear, janam kundli of whom?

Comment: What exactly do you mean - i thought navagraha refers to the planets and nodes put together -  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navagraha

Comment: @Manu If I understand the question correctly, normally in everyone's natal chart, there will be placement of grahas like sun, moon etc. But what will be there in the natal charts of sun or moon themselves? Can sun be present in his own natal chart?

Comment: Kundli is created with respect to earth, as in how planets are aligned when seen from earth. Don't think it is possible to have kundli if not on earth because scriptures don't have characteristics of earth or it's relationship with other planets.

Comment: But this brings up a question. Can kundli be created for a human born in space ? Or can predictions include transit effects for an astronomer in space

Comment: @Carmensandiego Thats the first thought I got, but I have heard of astrological explanations (like saadesaathi) for why certain gods went through bad periods of time etcetra.

Comment: @Carmensandiego Yes, for both questions.

Comment: Well in that case got to know the influence of earth of a being born in another planet. Don't think there is mention of such a thing in any treatise. Btw interested in seeing references of God being saadesathi. One story was about Meghanad birth where all planets were kept in 11th house, and then Shani Dev doing some mischief and thus we have a gullika. Not sure if there is mention of it in a scripture. Besides event was on Earth

Comment: Janam Kundali exists for everything that exists. It has nothing to do with earth. If Saturn was born last, which he was, in his janam kundali everyone will be present except Saturn himself.

Comment: @SangitaSaxena Rama's kundali is decribed in ramayana.

Answer (score 0):

The **[Janam Kundli](https://www.astroyogi.com/kundli/)**, also known as the birth chart, depicts the positions of celestial bodies at the time of an individual's birth. It includes the positions of the nine grahas or planets, namely Surya (Sun), Chandra (Moon), Mangal (Mars), Budh (Mercury), Guru (Jupiter), Shukra (Venus), Shani (Saturn), Rahu (North Lunar Node), and Ketu (South Lunar Node). Each graha occupies a specific house in the Kundli, influencing various aspects of life based on its placement and aspects.

For example, Surya graha represents vitality, authority, and ego, while Chandra graha signifies emotions, intuition, and motherhood. The Kundli visually represents these grahas as symbols placed within specific sections or houses, indicating their positions relative to the zodiac signs and other celestial bodies. Astrologers analyze the placement, strength, and relationships between these grahas to provide insights into an individual's personality, life events, and potential challenges.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).